# ffmpeg: possible to encode zerolatency stream with only P frames?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm experimenting with extracting motion vectors from h.264 videos for some vision task and I was wondering whether it's possible with ffmpeg to encode a h.264 stream so that it consists only of P-Frames with all macroblocks being temporally predicted (so that all blocks contain motion vectors)?

If so, how?

Comment: Initial frame will be IDR. For the rest, set scenecut to 0 and keyint to a very high number.